# Can't update my app from play store

Tags: android, google-play

I updated my app on play store yesterday but I cant update my app to the new version. If I go to play store using my phone I dont get the update button.

**In the developer console:**
If I try to archive the latest version (11) and activate my previous version (10) it says:

> This configuration cannot be published for the following reason(s): It
>   is forbidden to downgrade devices which previously matched version 11
>   to version 10, which would occur when  API levels in range 10+ and 
>   Screen layouts containing any of [small, normal, large, xlarge] and 
>   Features containing all of [android.hardware.screen.PORTRAIT,
>   android.hardware.TOUCHSCREEN].
>
> Previously active APKs supported more devices than those in the draft
>   configuration. Some devices will not receive upgrades. Less Devices
>   currently running version 11 are no longer supported by the current
>   configuration. Such devices will not receive upgrades.  API levels in
>   range 10+ and  Screen layouts containing any of [small, normal, large,
>   xlarge] and  Features containing all of
>   [android.hardware.screen.PORTRAIT, android.hardware.TOUCHSCREEN]

---

This was added in my AndroidManifest in version 11.

```
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="10" android:targetSdkVersion="17" /> // Previously was targetSdkVersion 16
<provider android:name=".DatabaseContentProvider" android:authorities="com.blabla.blabla.contentProvider" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.android.vending.CHECK_LICENSE" />
```

As you can see I implemented Googles LVL in this version.

Complete AndroidManifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.asd.asd"
    android:versionCode="11"
    android:versionName="2.0.0">

    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="10" android:targetSdkVersion="17" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="com.android.vending.CHECK_LICENSE" />

    <application
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar"
        android:allowBackup="true">
        <activity
            android:name="com.asd.asd.LicenseCheck"
            android:label="@string/app_name">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.asd.asd.MyActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" 
            android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:name="com.asd.asd.PreferenceActivity"
            android:label="@string/settings_name" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:name="com.asd.asd.AboutActivity"
            android:label="@string/about_name" >
        </activity>
        <receiver android:name="com.asd.asd.AlarmReceiver" />
        <receiver android:name="com.asd.asd.NotificationReceiver" />
        <service android:name="com.asd.asd.TimerService" />
        <provider android:name=".DatabaseContentProvider" 
            android:authorities="com.asd.asd.contentProvider" />
    </application>

</manifest>
```

I cant see why I cant update the application. And I dont understand why It's complaining about screensizes, portrait and touchscreen. I have never declared those specifics in my manifest.

**Edit:**
I found that I had removed this from the manifest:

```
<compatible-screens android:xlargeScreens="false"/>
```

Could it be this that is causes the issues? I Do whant to support xlargescreens now, thats why I removed it.

Comment: Try waiting for a couple more days. Google Play can be slow when putting out updates.

Comment: In the play store I says it is the latest version 2.0.0. So it seems like it has been published.

Comment: It has been published, but Google takes time to push the update to all the servers.

Comment: Oh I see @RaghavSood. I'll wait then and see what happends. This is the app [link](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.unzippedlabs.timeswipe) hopefully it will push the updates soon. It usually goes in a few hours, thats why I was worried when its starting to take 1 day.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@RagnhavSood was right. It took some time to get the update out (about 24h), it now works on my other phone at home but not on my own phone since it's tied to the developer account. I guess the problem for me could be that I implemented LVL so I cant update my own app.

All credits Raghav Sood